# How to customize the start up icon of Nvidia Visual Profiler

Tags: nvidia, gnome, java, cuda, openjdk

According to this [Nvidia Visual Profiler (nvvp) documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#visual), Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 1.8 must be available on the local system for it to work.

The installation of OpenJRE can be done via:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Thereafter, I can call up nvvp via:

```
nvvp -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

After installing NVIDIA CUDA v10.2 or v11, I noticed that after clicking on the Nvidia Visual Profiler icon in the GNOME desktop, the startup of nvvp always fail due to

```
> !MESSAGE Application error
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.nvidia.viper.application.application" could  not be found in the registry.
```

and and I think this has something to do with `nvvp` not detecting JRE
.

**Question:**

I would like to configure that Nvidia Visual Profiler icon to execute command `nvvp -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`. How do I make this configuration change in Ubuntu 18.04?